# How do I force tJavaFlex to generate multiple rows for a single row

Tags: talend

How do I make tJavaFlex generate multiple output rows for a single input row?  I don't want to use tSplitRow as I have to do other processing.

But for example, if I add a for loop inside my main code, and split my string into words the below happens, and I just get the last word in the sentence in my output flow:

tRowGenerator generating one sentence (1 row, one column):

[image]

tJavaFlex with loop in the Main section splitting the sentence into word tokens:

[image]

And this is what I get:

[image]

I had thought my loop would generate 10 rows in the output.  Is there a way to make the tJavaFlex do this kind of multiplication of input rows?

Comment: Maybe you can find here : http://etl-tips.blogspot.fr/2011/02/talend-le-composant-tjavaflex.html  It's in french but with a google translate it's ok.

Comment: Thanks, although not sure this answers the question

Comment: mind blown, just read the blog for a third time and the last "}" is placed in the END section, while the start of the loop is in the MAIN section, what on earth is happening there?

Comment: have you tried to add the closing parenthesis to the end code of yours?

Comment: Will do when back in office, although would want to understand it before I used it.  Need to dig into the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to achieve your requirement, you need to use component `tnormalize`.

Below is just a sample job using `tNormalize` component and I have used the same string that you have used

[image]

I have provided `item separator` as **"space"**

[image]

I have got the below result for simple println statement

[image]

Hope this may help you out.

Comment: Hi,  I ended up using tNormalize in the end, thanks for getting back to me.  I can see I have to be very careful with tJavaFlex.

Comment: I assume the answer is you can't make a tJavaFlex produce more than one row per input row...without doing some crazy stuff which really seems counter intuitive and requires a deep understanding on the generated code.  I will accept this answer